# NET Core Visual Studio 2015 Tools Installation does only install x64 SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

NET Core Visual Studio 2015 Tools Installation does only install x64 SDK.

It downloaded it from here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Even though it says there it will install both versions (x64 + x86) but x86 is missing:
[image: Program and Features]
Where do I find an exe that installs both?

Answer (score 1):

Please Install visual studio Community version 2015/2017

[from here](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) It will resolve your issue